# 3D objects not appearing in live action tracked footage render, but they do appear in rendered preview or material shading mode

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, compositing-nodes

My objects appear just fine in all material preview or rendered modes, but when I actually render out a frame or go to the compositing tab none of my objects are included in the final render. It just shows the background footage. Cycles camera ray visibility is enabled, none of my objects are hidden / disabled for rendering, and as far as I can tell my composition nodes are set up correctly.

Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5tv6.jpg) to an imgur gallery of my issue:
Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C3zqO-Nu8rfnLikNJlW_hyRdQMqp5EYA/view?usp=sharing) to my .blend file:

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated as I'm at the end of my wits with this. I've been troubleshooting integrating 3D elements with live action footage for days now, and it doesn't seem like anyone else has had this issue, and if they have, haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: welcome to stack exchange. If you provide blend files - which is really helpful and good - please use https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions. If you provide it by other providers like google you should definitely NOT do it in that way, that the helping person has to ask for permission.

Comment: Could you please show us your compositor setup?

Comment: Also could I suggest you use https://blend-exchange.com/ to upload, and share files?

Comment: Sure thing! The blend-exchange file is currently processing, but here is my node setup: https://imgur.com/5SNID2Q

Sorry about not using blend-exchange to begin with, I didn't know it was a thing.